# MarkLogic Cluster Upgrade Sequence

Tags: marklogic-9

I'm trying to determine the correct upgrade process for a 3 node cluster running 9.x sitting behind a load balancer.

Looking at the cluster configuration we find :

- Node 1 has forests and is the boot node ( likely the d-node ) and 300GB free.
- Node 2 has no forests and has 700 GB free disk space ( likely an e-node ).
- Node 3 has no forests and has 700 GB free disk space ( likely an e-node ).

Can I confirm that the correct cluster upgrade sequence from 9.x to 10.x Server is :

1. Shutdown node 3,2,1 ( in that order )
2. Deinstall converters then deinstall Server 9.x from Node 1
3. Deinstall converters then deinstall Server 9.x from Node 2 and Node 3
4. Install Server 10.x then install converters on Node 1 & restart Node 1
5. Install Server 10.x then install converters on Node 2 & 3 and restart both nodes.

Have I missed anything?

Is there anything I can look for on each node that tells me specifically that a node is an e-node or d-node?

Thanks.

Comment: Nodes are considered a D-node if they have forests (Data). They are considred E-nodes if they have appservers that clients connect to to Evaluate queries. A node can be E/D if it has both an appserver and hosts database forests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are attempting to perform a [rolling-upgrade](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/rolling-upgrades#id_33493) (probably not necessary for a small 3-node cluster that only has one D-node), it is easiest to just shut them all down, uninstall the converters and MarkLogic, install the new version of server and converters, then start them all up and complete the upgrade in the Admin UI.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/procedures#id_77358

> 1. Stop MarkLogic Server (as described in step 1 of Removing MarkLogic).
> 2. Uninstall the old MarkLogic 9 release (as described in Removing MarkLogic).
>    If you want to uninstall MarkLogic 9.0-4 or later, and if the converters package was previously installed with it, you will have to perform a two-step uninstall: first uninstall MarkLogic Converters and then uninstall MarkLogic Server. For more detail, see MarkLogic Converters Installation Changes Starting at Release 9.0-4 and Removing MarkLogic.
> 3. Install the new MarkLogic 10 release (as described in Installing MarkLogic).
> 4. If you want to install MarkLogic 9.0-4 or later, and you plan to use the converters package with it, you will have to perform a two-step installation: first install MarkLogic Server and then install MarkLogic Converters. For more detail, see MarkLogic Converters Installation Changes Starting at Release 9.0-4 and Installing MarkLogic.
> 5. Start MarkLogic Server (as described in Starting MarkLogic Server).
> 6. Open the Admin Interface in a browser (http://localhost:8001/).
> 7. When the Admin Interface prompts you to upgrade the databases and the configuration files, click the button to confirm the upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This cluster also has a data hub on it, can I confirm that after upgrading the server version, I can just run the normal data hub upgrade gradle commands on the boot / control node, and it will then update the data hub on the other 2 nodes through the cluster? Thanks.